# Json file to csv in Python

Tags: python, json, csv

If I use this script to convert from Json to Csv in Python:

```
import json

import csv

with open("data.json") as file:
    data = json.loads(file)

with open("data.csv", "w") as file:
    csv_file = csv.writer(file)
    for item in data:
        csv_file.writerow([item['studio'], item['title']] +    item['release_dates'].values())
```

It throws an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>

File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: Try `data = json.load(file)` instead of `data = json.loads(file)`. `loads` is meant for a string.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `json.loads()` when you should be using `json.load()`.

`json.loads` is for reading from a string, whereas `json.load` is for reading from a file.

Visit here for more information: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html.

Also, unrelated, but you can chain `with` statements.

```
with open("data.json") as json_file, open("data.csv", "w") as csv_file:
    csv_file = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for item in json.load(json_file):
        csv_file.writerow(...)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.json'    I get this error if I make that change.

Comment: That error looks like it's happening on the `open()` line, not the `json.load` line.

Comment: It is not able to find the location of the file. I have kept the file in the python folder inside the program files. Still unable to access. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
 File"C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 268, in load parse_constant=parse_constant,object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
 File"C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads return _default_decoder.decode(s)
 File"C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 2065)